# git, SSH_ASKPASS on windows

Tags: windows, git, ssh, msysgit

I am writing a graphical git frontend for Linux and Windows
[(MSEgit)](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mseuniverse/) based on [MSEide+MSEgui](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mseide-msegui/). MSEgit has an internal console window which communicates with git by pipes. On Linux it uses a PTY so SSH asks for key unlocking passwords on the PTY.
On Windows I wrote a small password entry application and set the SSH_ASKPASS environment variable accordingly.
SSH calls the password application if git is started with CreateProcess() dwCreationFlags DETACHED_PROCESS set but the password entry window will not be focused, its taskbar icon flashes instead.
SSH does not run the password application if FreeConsole() is called to be sure that there is no attached console to MSEgit and git is started without DETACHED_PROCESS but CREATE_NO_WINDOW instead.
I assume a Windows equivalent of POSIX setsid() should be called.
How can I force SSH to use SSH_ASKPASS without the DETACHED_PROCESS flag?
If this is not possible, how can I ensure that the password entry window is focused?

Comment: It seems that this is no longer required when using Git for Windows 2.x

Answer (score 0):

On windows a child process is not allowed to take focus away from a parent unless it gets permission. The parent should call [AllowSetForegroundWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632668%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to provide that permission. Then the child process can become foreground and set its focus appropriately.

Comment: That works in order to get focus on password window, thanks. AFAIK child processes should get focus if created by the foreground process, MSDN: "A process can set the foreground window only if one of the following conditions is true:

    The process is the foreground process.
    The process was started by the foreground process. [...]". It seems DETACHED_PROCESS inhibits that rule.